# sql many to many relationship with only 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

So I have two tables I need to join for a client. These tables only share 1 field in common (COLOR, and it isn't a unique key ident). Is is possible to join/relate these two tables?

So let's say theoretically I have two tables with COLOR and a COLOR ATTRIBUTE, as follows:

```
+-------+----------+
| COLOR |   NAME   |
+-------+----------+
| red   | brian    |
| red   | ben      |
| red   | tom      |
| red   | jennifer |
| blue  | tom      |
| blue  | billy    |
| blue  | michelle |
+-------+----------+
```

And another table that is ONLY related by the color column, but has multiple color weights:

```
+-------+--------+
| COLOR | WEIGHT |
+-------+--------+
| red   |     12 |
| red   |      3 |
| red   |     11 |
| blue  |      4 |
| blue  |     23 |
| blue  |      7 |
| blue  |      5 |
| blue  |     10 |
+-------+--------+
```

So how can I join these two tables given ONLY the color column is shared? What would the result look like? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *What would the result look like?* Just try it. The actual questions is: What result do you want?

Comment: is the only solution to have "red" multiply for each person onto the weight table, making red appear 4x3 = 12 times? And blue would be 3x5=15 times?

Comment: that would be the standard response, yes. Do you want something else?

Comment: In case an actual question comes out of this, please fix your tags and only leave the database system you use (Access / Sql Server / MySql)

Comment: Didn't mean to step on toes Andre, but I'm using both Access and SQL server because Access crashes when I try to run the queries (over 2gig memory limit). If this is the correct answer of multiplying the records, then I guess I need to find a workaround to create this massive query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While *color* is not a unique identifier, if you plan to perform a join on it, it will be treated as such.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.COLOR = t2.COLOR
ORDER BY COLOR DESC;
```

This outputs three columns with 12 "red rows" and 15 "blue rows."